# how to use document.getElementByTagName and target specific class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code here.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="accordionHeader">
<h1 onclick="test()"></h1>
</div>
<div class="accordionContent" style="display:none">
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to target and show/hide class="accordionContent". Ive tried using document.getElementByTagName but I dont know how to target the class="accordionContent". Im not allowed to use id.

Hope you could help me. Tries searching but no luck.

Comment: There is no `getElementByTagName`. Perhaps you mean element**s**

Comment: You'll have to iterate through the list yourself, or else use `querySelectorAll()` (which isn't universally supported).  Since you tagged your post with jQuery, you really should just use it.

Comment: Good reading: [jQuery Basic Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/)

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this with jquery

```
$('.accordionContent').show(); //to show


$('.accordionContent').hide(); //to hide
```

or even  toggle can work :)

```
$('.accordionContent').toggle(); //to hide and show 

$('.accordionContent').slideToggle(); //toggle with Animatation

$('.accordionContent').fadeIn(); //fadeIn with Animatation
$('.accordionContent').fadeOut(); //FadeOut with Animatation
```

choose any one, which ever you feel comfortable :)

Comment: Thanks, one thing more, at the same time, when h1 is clicked <div class="accordionHeader"> will change its y position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **getElementByClassName** and hide/show accordionContent div as follow:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('accordionContent')[0].style.display="show";  // to show

document.getElementsByClassName('accordionContent')[0].style.display="show";  // to hide
```